# Karate labs framework- Null value click

Tags: karate, ui-automation, shadow-dom

How to click on an element inside a **section** in a shadow DOM in Karate labs framework?
There is a single shadow root inside a DOM which contains a section that I want to click.
I have tried using script followed by JSPath, followed by .click(), the test is getting passed but it is NOT GETTING CLICKED.

I have tried using script followed by JSPath, followed by .click(), the test is getting passed but it is NOT GETTING CLICKED.
tried to print giving value null.
I need help on how can I click on and element inside a section of a shadow DOM.